# Build-Max-Heap: Why Start i at floor(A.length/2) rather than A.length?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, heaps

Taken from CLRS third edition, a procedure is given for Build-Max-Heap

```
function a = build_MaxHeap(a)
for i = floor(length(a)/2): -1 : 1        // i = n downto 1
     a = max_heapify(a,i);
end
```

My question is why use floor(length(a)/2)? How is it different than using length(a)? Is this the same thing?

```
function a = build_MaxHeap(a)
for i = length(a): -1 : 1        // i = n downto 1
     a = max_heapify(a,i);
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It isn't, neither from a complexity nor from a correctness point of view, however, by starting the counter at $n$ you are doing useless work.

Heapify is a procedure that, if invoked on a node $v$ such that the trees rooted in its children are binary heaps, turns the tree rooted in $v$ into a binary heap. Trees that contain only one node are trivially binary heaps, therefore, you may just start running the algorithm from the first non-leaf node: invoking heapify on the leaves wouldn't have done anything, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There are already some answers, but I wanted to provide a maybe more straightforward explanation.

Inside your `max_heapify` function, you compare the value of the root node (this is the `i` parameter) with the values of its children. The children are located at indices like `2*i+1`, `2*i+2`.

So what happens in `max_heapify` if `2*i`+ is outside the bounds of the array?

It won't swap anything or continue down the tree at all, it'll likely just be a no-op. So, there's no difference effectively.

Answer (score 1):

In a binary max-heap, each node at a index $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 1, \lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 2, \cdots , n$ is a leaf and is thus root of a trivial max-heap.

I am assuming that max-heap representation is like below.

*PARENT($i$)*

1 **return** $\lfloor i / 2 \rfloor$

*Left($i$)*

1 **return** $2i$

*Right($i$)*

1 **return** $2i + 1$

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why use floor(length(a)/2)? How is it different than using length(a)? Is this the same thing?

Since every node at index $⌊/2⌋+1,⌊/2⌋+2,⋯,$ is a leaf node, it is also a root of a subtree max-heap. So no difference.

However, I want to point to another question, perhaps more interesting:

> Why do we go backwards and don't start from 1 up to floor(length(a)/2)?

The answer lies in the assumptions made by `max-heapify` procedure:

```
When it is called, MAX-HEAPIFY assumes that the binary trees rooted at LEFT(i)
and RIGHT(i) are max-heaps, but that A[i] might be smaller than its children,
thus violating the max-heap property.
```

Example: `A = [5, 3, 4, 9, 6, 1, 2]`, if you start from the first element (`5`), it's left subtree (`3->9, 3->6`) is not itself a max-heap.
Since the assumption is violated, you're not guaranteed to get correct max-heap data structure if you don't start backwards from the middle.